# Changing Windows 8/8.1 Install Date

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Please can someone point me to the registry key that the `Original Install Date` when you run `systeminfo` is stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate` contains the install date in Unix timestamp format.